# Can not find Incrementantal State Transfer documentation for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, galera

I can find [State Snapshot Transfers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/state-snapshot-transfers-ssts-in-galera-cluster/) documentation for MariaDB, but can not find the same documentation for **IST**.

IST is mentioned indeed on [Configuring MariaDB Galera Cluster](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-galera-cluster/) page, under the title "Network Ports", but no link provided for IST documentation. (neither Google find and MariaDB native doc on this topic)

Comment: See also Galera documentation.

Comment: Many thx, I am seeing it too, but that is so MySQL specific and I have MariaDB. I know it is similar, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: [Incremental State Transfer (IST)](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/state-transfer.html)

Comment: @danblack, many thx, that is the galera cluster doc, applies to mysql, not mariadb, see my prev, comment...

Comment: No, it applies to MariaDB too. IST is a component totally within galera. MariaDB (and MySQL) have no visibility on how IST is done.

Comment: @danblack, maybe that was I missing.